# Does This Moving Rocket Use CSS3 (Animation)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Do you think [this rocket](http://demo.drythemes.com/thebigbang/) use CSS3 (Animation)? Or, jQuery?
I try to understand the CSS wrote by the web designer and I couldn't find any style to make the rocket moving.

How to do that kind of animation? 
Do share your ideas and tutorials guys if you have one. I want to learn this kind of animation.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not:

Let me tell you why so you can figure it out yourself next time.

In Google Chrome, use the "Right-Click" -> "Inspect Element" action right over the rocket.  Chrome should automatically select the rocket and you can see inline something like this:

`<img class="floating-rocket" src="images/rocket.png" alt="Launching" style="margin-top: -90.86px; margin-left: -510.43px; ">`

This part: `style="margin-top: -90.86px; margin-left: -510.43px; "` is changing dynamically, shifting the rocket back and forth.  This behavior cannot be done with CSS. You can double check this also by noticing that the affected tag is an `img` tag and that there are no CSS animation properties.

The inline style changing is very typical of Javascript.  In fact, if you look at Javascript files attached to the page, you'll find this:

http://demo.drythemes.com/thebigbang/js/custom/customUI.js

Which contains the actual javascript that moves the rocket.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

http://demo.drythemes.com/thebigbang/js/custom/customUI.js

Has the rocket animation:

```
$('.floating-rocket').everyTime(10, function () {
            $(".floating-rocket").animate({
                marginTop: "+=10",
                marginLeft: "+=5"
            }, 1000, 'linear').animate({
                marginTop: "-=10",
                marginLeft: "-=5"
            }, 1000, 'linear');
    });
```

Comment: Btw, what does 'everyTime(10,' and '1000, 'linear'' means here?

Comment: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/timers and http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2):

It does use Javascript animation.

Use the Chrome Dev Tools to figure it out. In Chrome, right-click on the rocket and click "Inspect element".

I recommend you to use CSS animations for this, not like this website.

Here is a a example on how to do it:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rocket {
   from {
    margin-left: -510px;
    margin-top: -90px;
   }
   to {
    margin-left: -500px;
    margin-top: -100px
   }
}
.rocket {
 -webkit-animation: rocket 1s alternate infinite linear;
}
```

Of course, don't forget to prefix :D I think this solution is better because CSS > Javascript and if you want scale or rotation, you can add that easily!

Comment: Btw, what does 'alternate infinite linear' means here?

Comment: 'alternate' makes that the animation goes back if it's finished and doesn't start from beginning. It basically animates back to the start position. 'infinite' makes that the animation never stops, you could set that after a certain number of repeats, the animation will stop. Useful for animations you just wanna make once. 'linear' is a easing function, it does make the animation go equally fast all the time. You can use other values here as well, maybe it will look even better. Look here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/ I just used it because the sample was too :D